# Как устранить конфликт скриптов jquery?

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте. Пытаюсь в шаблон вордпресс со слайдером прикрутить плавно выпадающее меню. Скрипты слайдера:

```
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/jdgallery/mootools-1.2.5-core-yc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/jdgallery/mootools-1.2-more.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/jdgallery/jd.gallery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/jdgallery/jd.gallery.transitions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Скрипты меню:

```
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/customscript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/modernizr.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Когда прописываю скрипты меню то перестает работать слайдер. Для того, чтобы он заработал достаточно убрать:

```
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

но тогда меню теряет плавность. 
Пробовал jQuery.noConflict(); с заменой $ на jQuery в файле jquery.min.js - не работает меню. Если это возможно, то подскажите подробно как сделать чтобы устранить этот конфликт.
Файл customscript.js:

```
/*
 * Superfish v1.4.8 - jQuery menu widget
 * Copyright (c) 2008 Joel Birch
 *
 * Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses:
 *  http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 *  http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
 *
 * CHANGELOG: http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/changelog.txt
 */
(function($){$.fn.superfish=function(op){var sf=$.fn.superfish,c=sf.c,$arrow=$(['<span class="',c.arrowClass,'"> &#xbb;</span>'].join("")),over=function(){var $$=$(this),menu=getMenu($$);clearTimeout(menu.sfTimer);$$.showSuperfishUl().siblings().hideSuperfishUl();},out=function(){var $$=$(this),menu=getMenu($$),o=sf.op;clearTimeout(menu.sfTimer);menu.sfTimer=setTimeout(function(){o.retainPath=($.inArray($$[0],o.$path)>-1);$$.hideSuperfishUl();if(o.$path.length&&$$.parents(["li.",o.hoverClass].join("")).length<1){over.call(o.$path);}},o.delay);},getMenu=function($menu){var menu=$menu.parents(["ul.",c.menuClass,":first"].join(""))[0];sf.op=sf.o[menu.serial];return menu;},addArrow=function($a){$a.addClass(c.anchorClass).append($arrow.clone());};return this.each(function(){var s=this.serial=sf.o.length;var o=$.extend({},sf.defaults,op);o.$path=$("li."+o.pathClass,this).slice(0,o.pathLevels).each(function(){$(this).addClass([o.hoverClass,c.bcClass].join(" ")).filter("li:has(ul)").removeClass(o.pathClass);});sf.o[s]=sf.op=o;$("li:has(ul)",this)[($.fn.hoverIntent&&!o.disableHI)?"hoverIntent":"hover"](over,out).each(function(){if(o.autoArrows){addArrow($(">a:first-child",this));}}).not("."+c.bcClass).hideSuperfishUl();var $a=$("a",this);$a.each(function(i){var $li=$a.eq(i).parents("li");$a.eq(i).focus(function(){over.call($li);}).blur(function(){out.call($li);});});o.onInit.call(this);}).each(function(){var menuClasses=[c.menuClass];if(sf.op.dropShadows&&!($.browser.msie&&$.browser.version<7)){menuClasses.push(c.shadowClass);}$(this).addClass(menuClasses.join(" "));});};var sf=$.fn.superfish;sf.o=[];sf.op={};sf.IE7fix=function(){var o=sf.op;if($.browser.msie&&$.browser.version>6&&o.dropShadows&&o.animation.opacity!=undefined){this.toggleClass(sf.c.shadowClass+"-off");}};sf.c={bcClass:"sf-breadcrumb",menuClass:"sf-js-enabled",anchorClass:"sf-with-ul",arrowClass:"sf-sub-indicator",shadowClass:"sf-shadow"};sf.defaults={hoverClass:"sfHover",pathClass:"overideThisToUse",pathLevels:1,delay:800,animation:{opacity:"show"},speed:"normal",autoArrows:true,dropShadows:true,disableHI:false,onInit:function(){},onBeforeShow:function(){},onShow:function(){},onHide:function(){}};$.fn.extend({hideSuperfishUl:function(){var o=sf.op,not=(o.retainPath===true)?o.$path:"";o.retainPath=false;var $ul=$(["li.",o.hoverClass].join(""),this).add(this).not(not).removeClass(o.hoverClass).find(">ul").hide().css("visibility","hidden");o.onHide.call($ul);return this;},showSuperfishUl:function(){var o=sf.op,sh=sf.c.shadowClass+"-off",$ul=this.addClass(o.hoverClass).find(">ul:hidden").css("visibility","visible");sf.IE7fix.call($ul);o.onBeforeShow.call($ul);$ul.animate(o.animation,o.speed,function(){sf.IE7fix.call($ul);o.onShow.call($ul);});return this;}});})(jQuery);

    $(document).ready(function($) {

    $('ul.menu, ul#children, ul.sub-menu').superfish({ 
        delay:       100,                               // 0.1 second delay on mouseout 
        animation:   {opacity:'show',height:'show'},    // fade-in and slide-down animation 
        dropShadows: false                              // disable drop shadows 
    });

});

$(document).ready(function() {
    // Create the dropdown base
   $("<select />").appendTo("#navigation");

      // Create default option "Go to..."
      $("<option />", {
         "selected": "selected",
         "value"   : "",
         "text"    : "Go to..."
      }).appendTo("#navigation select");

      // Populate dropdown with menu items
      $("#navigation > ul > li:not([data-toggle])").each(function() {

        var el = $(this);

        var hasChildren = el.find("ul"),
            children    = el.find("li > a");

        if (hasChildren.length) {

            $("<optgroup />", {
                "label": el.find("> a").text()
            }).appendTo("#navigation select");

            children.each(function() {

                $("<option />", {
                    "value"   : $(this).attr("href"),
                    "text": " - " + $(this).text()
                }).appendTo("optgroup:last");

            });

        } else {

            $("<option />", {
               "value"   : el.find("> a").attr("href"),
               "text"    : el.find("> a").text()
           }).appendTo("#navigation select");

        }

      });

      $("#navigation select").change(function() {
        window.location = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
      });

    //END -- Menus to <SELECT>

    }); //END -- JQUERY document.ready

jQuery(document).ready(function(){

        // UL = .tabs
        // Tab contents = .inside

       var tag_cloud_class = '#tag-cloud';

              //Fix for tag clouds - unexpected height before .hide() 
            var tag_cloud_height = jQuery('#tag-cloud').height();

       jQuery('.inside ul li:last-child').css('border-bottom','0px') // remove last border-bottom from list in tab conten
       jQuery('.tabs').each(function(){
        jQuery(this).children('li').children('a:first').addClass('selected'); // Add .selected class to first tab on load
       });
       jQuery('.inside > *').hide();
       jQuery('.inside > *:first-child').show();

       jQuery('.tabs li a').click(function(evt){ // Init Click funtion on Tabs

            var clicked_tab_ref = jQuery(this).attr('href'); // Strore Href value

            jQuery(this).parent().parent().children('li').children('a').removeClass('selected'); //Remove selected from all tabs
            jQuery(this).addClass('selected');
            jQuery(this).parent().parent().parent().children('.inside').children('*').hide();

            /*
            if(clicked_tab_ref === tag_cloud_class) // Initiate tab fix (+20 for padding fix)
            {
                clicked_tab_ref_height = tag_cloud_height + 20;
            }
            else // Other height calculations
            {
                clicked_tab_ref_height = jQuery('.inside ' + clicked_tab_ref).height();
            }
            */
             //jQuery('.inside').stop().animate({
            //    height: clicked_tab_ref_height
            // },400,"linear",function(){
                    //Callback after new tab content's height animation
                    jQuery('.inside ' + clicked_tab_ref).fadeIn(500);
            // })

             evt.preventDefault();

        })

})

// Scroll to Top script
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('a[href=#top]').click(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');
        return false;
    });
$(".togglec").hide();

        $(".togglet").click(function(){

        $(this).toggleClass("toggleta").next(".togglec").slideToggle("normal");
           return true;
        });
});

function swt_format_twitter(twitters) {
  var statusHTML = [];
  for (var i=0; i<twitters.length; i++){
    var username = twitters[i].user.screen_name;
    var status = twitters[i].text.replace(/((https?|s?ftp|ssh)\:\/\/[^"\s\<\>]*[^.,;'">\:\s\<\>\)\]\!])/g, function(url) {
      return '<a href="'+url+'">'+url+'</a>';
    }).replace(/\B@([_a-z0-9]+)/ig, function(reply) {
      return  reply.charAt(0)+'<a href="http://twitter.com/'+reply.substring(1)+'">'+reply.substring(1)+'</a>';
    });
    statusHTML.push('<li><span>'+status+'</span> <a style="font-size:90%; color:#bbb;" href="http://twitter.com/'+username+'/statuses/'+twitters[i].id_str+'">'+relative_time(twitters[i].created_at)+'</a></li>');
  }
  return statusHTML.join('');
}

function relative_time(time_value) {
  var values = time_value.split(" ");
  time_value = values[1] + " " + values[2] + ", " + values[5] + " " + values[3];
  var parsed_date = Date.parse(time_value);
  var relative_to = (arguments.length > 1) ? arguments[1] : new Date();
  var delta = parseInt((relative_to.getTime() - parsed_date) / 1000);
  delta = delta + (relative_to.getTimezoneOffset() * 60);

  if (delta < 60) {
    return 'less than a minute ago';
  } else if(delta < 120) {
    return 'about a minute ago';
  } else if(delta < (60*60)) {
    return (parseInt(delta / 60)).toString() + ' minutes ago';
  } else if(delta < (120*60)) {
    return 'about an hour ago';
  } else if(delta < (24*60*60)) {
    return 'about ' + (parseInt(delta / 3600)).toString() + ' hours ago';
  } else if(delta < (48*60*60)) {
    return '1 day ago';
  } else {
    return (parseInt(delta / 86400)).toString() + ' days ago';
  }
}
```

Comment: @Дмитрий80, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: Не надо менять jquery.min.js . А вообще все зависит от того что у вас в customscript.js написано.

Comment: Добавил содержимое файла customscript.js

Comment: eicto, большое вам спасибо! Сделал как вы сказали - и меню и слайдер работает.

Comment: Второй раз обращаюсь сюда за помощью. В прошлый раз как-то проголосовал за подходящий совет. Сейчас снова никак не могу найти "галку", чтобы отметить ответ. Подскажите, пожалуйста, кто-нибудь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пропишите в начале `jQuery.noConflict()` (можно без присваивания)
замените все **`$(document).ready(function($){`** на **`jQuery(function($){`**

Comment: Спасибо, замена `$(document).ready(function($){` на `jQuery(function($){` помогла.
Еще поменял jquery на jQuery